# Help creating Custom Grub2 Entry for Parted Magic 2015 (Have working 2013)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I love parted magic, I want to be able to use the newest version. I got my custom entry from

[Help Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples#Parted_Magic)

and tweaked it a bit to my system and made it simpler.

It works with the version from the article, a 2013 version, but when I try with 2015 It gives the follow errors:

```
losetup /dev/loop252: No Such File or directory
mount : dev/loop252: can't read superblock
(In red highligted - next line)
Mounting the fu.sqfs failed.
```

-- It then takes me to the command line

bash-4.3#

---

Here is my simple custom grub menu entry:

```
menuentry "Parted Magic ISO" {
set isofile="/home/isos/pmagic.iso"
loopback loop $isofile
linux (loop)/pmagic/bzImage iso_filename=$isofile boot=live
initrd (loop)/pmagic/initrd.img
}
```

In reference to below comment, here is the original unmodified code from the link above..........

```
menuentry 'Parted Magic ISO ' {
set isofile="/iso/pmagic_2013_05_01.iso"
loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
linux (loop)/pmagic/bzImage iso_filename=/iso/pmagic_2013_05_01.iso boot=live
initrd (loop)/pmagic/initrd.img
}
```

The grub entry finds the ISO, the issue lies in the:

```
linux (loop)
initrd (loop)
```

lines of code

Comment: /home/isos does not seem right. /home would not be mounted if a separte partition until Ubuntu loads and /home/$USER is your normal mount. Did you create a new users as isos in /home? I often use a separate partition or include a iso folder in /boot so I know it is there. Some examples: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples

Comment: As stated, my version works fine for the 2013 pmagic. Please read entire post, as the link you shared is in the original post already. What ubuntu see's is irrelevant only what GRUB interprets is. I simply removed hd0,1, because I believe (I think i read somewhere) that it assumes (unless otherwise specified) that you are referencing the root/boot partition or the first partition. In my case my iso's are in the same partition as Ubuntu. (They are so small I don't mind redundant backups) The issue does not like in the first 3 lines, it lies in the 

linux (loop)
initrd (loop)

lines of the code

Comment: You still have to set root or use the search to find root. One that works does not have the /home/iso, just /iso which does make more sense.

Comment: getting off tanget a bit but... Here is where I garnered my simplified ideals from

[clonezilla live from hdd](http://clonezilla.org/livehd.php)

Notice there example

menuentry "Clonezilla live" {
set isofile="/home/isos/clonezilla-live-1.2.6-24.iso"
loopback loop $isofile

Comment: @OldFred, i saw this other link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2136963 where you helped somebody, I figued out how to do what I wanted, but I was curious, where can I find information about the flags in the custom entry, I don't like to just use an entry that works, I want to understand the flags, thanks!

Comment: The various boot parameters are those posted by others who have a version working. Sometimes the ISO's site has info. Sometimes you have to mount the ISO and see what parameters it uses. You may just have to search for its grub or syslinux or other boot file with example on its linux line or file with the parameters . But usually someone has posted an example.

Comment: Thanks, yea thats how I have been doing it, using examples online and trial and error, but i wish I could just find a man page for custom boot flags lol, looks like im out of luck, but the bottom one works I just posted, I tried removing as many flags as I could, only one I needed was load_ramdisk or the main partition would be locked because its loading fu.img and m**.img from the HD not the ISO

Comment: I only have Parted Magic 2013_08 verions. But if you mount ISO, and look at files you find these: Grub settings in efi folder
`set default_settings="edd=on vga=normal vmalloc=384MiB"`
Syslinux.cfg for BIOS
`APPEND edd=on vga=normal vmalloc=384MiB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parted Magic Custom Grub Entry

```
sudo mkdir /home/isos/
```

Copy iso to dir and rename pmagic.iso && for 2015 copy pmagic dir from ISO to root / (also need ISO, on top of pmagic dir)

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/isos/ -R
sudo chmod 777 /pmagic -R
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom && sudo update-grub2
```

### Custom Grub Entry

**2013 Version w/ just ISO**

```
menuentry "Parted Magic" {
set isofile="/home/isos/pmagic.iso"
loopback loop $isofile
linux (loop)/pmagic/bzImage iso_filename=$isofile boot=live
initrd (loop)/pmagic/initrd.img
}
```

**2015 Version 32-bit**

```
menuentry "Parted Magic" {
set isofile="/home/isos/pmagic.iso"
loopback loop $isofile
linux (loop)/pmagic/bzImage iso_filename=$isofile load_ramdisk=1
initrd (loop)/pmagic/initrd.img /pmagic/fu.img /pmagic/m32.img
}
```

**2015 Version 64-bit**

```
menuentry "Parted Magic" {
set isofile="/home/isos/pmagic.iso"
loopback loop $isofile
linux (loop)/pmagic/bzImage64 iso_filename=$isofile load_ramdisk=1
initrd (loop)/pmagic/initrd.img /pmagic/fu.img /pmagic/m64.img
}
```

An alias to use to reboot to ISO:

```
alias pmagic="sudo grub-reboot 'Parted Magic' && reboot"
```

Now your computer will auto reboot to Pmagic and when done, reboot and it will auto boot back into OS!(AKA Default Grub Entry)