# Customize ISO - SQFS -- Add Custom BashRC - Alias to Ubuntu Live DVD iso

Tags: iso, customization, bashrc

I would like to customize my Ubuntu Live iso and add an command alias that I use each time I load disk. This way I don't have to open my logs for the command(s) I use each time, mainly to start a vnc server.

```
alias vnc='chmod a+x /root/.xinitrc && vncserver :60'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## To remaster an ISO do the following:

*Also all commands are performed as root

## Copy the ISO to the tmp directory:

```
mkdir /tmp/cdrom
mkdir /tmp/iso
mount -o loop Linux.iso /tmp/cdrom
cp -a /tmp/cdrom /tmp/iso
umount /tmp/cdrom
```

cd into /tmp/iso and copy .*sqfs or *.squashfs to /tmp

```
unsquashfs /tmp/*.sqfs 
cd /tmp/squashfs-root/
```

Make Changes now Then...

```
mksquashfs /tmp/squashfs-root *.SQFS
```

So far the Only way I have managed to remaster the ISO is either if the ISO has a makeiso.script or by using ISOMaster to open the original ISO remove the old sqfs and then insert new one and remaster ISO.

Comment: here is a my post on creating custom grub entry for PMAGIC and rebooting server remotley to load PMAGIC into ram! [Custom Grub Entry for Pmagic 2015 and Reboot Alias](http://askubuntu.com/questions/636952/help-creating-custom-grub2-entry-for-parted-magic-2015-have-working-2013)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it would be like following through https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization to customize that ISO file.  Mainly, you would be extracting the `filesystem.squashfs` and modifying it.  The home folder within the `filesystem.squashfs` is `/etc/skel/`, that is where you would put your .bashrc, etc. files.  The `filesystem.squashfs` would then have to be resquashed and then added to the custom ISO.

The `/etc/skel/` folder is the default home folder for the Ubuntu Live CD/DVD/USB in the `filesystem.squashfs`.  I am not sure what OS the Parted Magic is using.  It could be different.

Hope this helps and points you in the right direction.

Comment: PMagic creator likes to make things different with each release, hence why the Grub Entry for 2013 does not work for 2015, but I found that to add alias to PMAGIC root user I edited, /etc/profile ...

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the iso, edit it, and then save it.  Then remount it to make sure your edits were retained, and if so, burn and test!  If all goes well, you've done it!

And just put the .bashrc in the home directory where the original was.

Comment: when I mount the ISO, its just the live files to run the ISO, a bunch of .sqfs .img .fu files

Comment: you've got to find the home directory.  What you boot off of the ISO, run this command: 'echo $HOME'